# [speed difference]make request as a function once a time vs make a list for requests to loop once

Tags: python

I wrote a program to help my colleagues to verify a link is accessible or not. I use requests library, but I came up 2 solutions.
Firstly I wrote this (ignore some unimportant methods):

```
class VerifyLink(object):
    ReadDirectory = 'read/'
    WriteDirectory = 'out/'

    @classmethod
    def verify_links(cls, url):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)
            return 'error'
        else:
            return r.status_code

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def start_verifying(self):
        target_data = self.data['Sheet1']
        index = 1
        while index < len(target_data):
            this_row = target_data[index]
            result = self.verify_links(this_row[1])
            print("%s %s" % (index, result))
            if result == 200:
                this_row.append('vaild')
            elif result == 'error':
                this_row.append('error')
            else:
                this_row.append('invaild')

            index += 1
```

I put the send requests process in a function.

Later then I thought that request seems to be a async library, would I benefit more from that if I extract all the links first then loop the links over without extra function calls?

Then I have this:

```
class VerifyLink(object):
    ReadDirectory = 'read/'
    WriteDirectory = 'out/'

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.links = None

    def verify_links(self):
        links = self.data['Sheet1']
        for index, link in enumerate(links):
            if index == 0:
                continue
            try:
                r = requests.get(link[1])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e.message)
                link.append('error')
            else:
                print("%s %s" % (index, r.status_code))
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    link.append('valid')
                else:
                    link.append('invalid')
```

Does these two really make a difference?

[repo_links](https://bitbucket.org/tianqing93/verify_link)

Comment: can you simplify your example, it is unclear what are you asking for

Comment: If you are wondering whether the second way would be more efficient, I'd suggest you to log time spent on the two ways and see if there is any difference by yourself.

Comment: Calling (getting in and out of) a function, clearly introduces overhead. Also *Python*ic `for` (might also be referred to as _foreach_) is faster than `while`. But both of these are performance "fine tunning" operations, and I'm not sure if their benefits would be visible when combined with accessing websites (which involves a time consuming set of actions).